# JPA is somehow reverting Entity Bean Primary Key to Deafult

Tags: jpa, jsf, merge, ejb

So i have an entity, thats managed by entitymanager in and ejb bean and has a primary key, thats auto incremented as follows:

```
package si.um.jpa.vao;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Vaja {

    private int idVaje;
    private String nazivVaje, sifraVaje, delTelesa, naprava, opis, slika, video;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int getIdVaje() {
        return idVaje;
    }
    public void setIdVaje(int idVaje) {
        this.idVaje = idVaje;
    }
    public String getNazivVaje() {
        return nazivVaje;
    }
    public void setNazivVaje(String nazivVaje) {
        this.nazivVaje = nazivVaje;
    }
    public String getSifraVaje() {
        return sifraVaje;
    }
    public void setSifraVaje(String sifraVaje) {
        this.sifraVaje = sifraVaje;
    }
    public String getDelTelesa() {
        return delTelesa;
    }
    public void setDelTelesa(String delTelesa) {
        this.delTelesa = delTelesa;
    }
    public String getNaprava() {
        return naprava;
    }
    public void setNaprava(String naprava) {
        this.naprava = naprava;
    }
    public String getOpis() {
        return opis;
    }
    public void setOpis(String opis) {
        this.opis = opis;
    }
    public String getSlika() {
        return slika;
    }
    public void setSlika(String slika) {
        this.slika = slika;
    }
    public String getVideo() {
        return video;
    }
    public void setVideo(String video) {
        this.video = video;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Vaja [idVaje=" + idVaje + ", nazivVaje=" + nazivVaje + ", sifraVaje=" + sifraVaje + ", delTelesa="
                + delTelesa + ", naprava=" + naprava + ", opis=" + opis + ", slika=" + slika + ", video=" + video + "]";
    }
}
```

then i have the ejb that manages the entity as follows:

```
package si.um.jpa3.ejb;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import si.um.jpa.vao.Vaja;
import si.um.jpa2.jsf.VajeJSFBean;

@Stateless
public class VajeBean implements VajeBeanLocal {

    Logger log=LoggerFactory.getLogger(VajeBean.class);

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void dodajVajo(Vaja v) {
        log.info("VajeBean: dodajVajo");
        if(najdi(v.getIdVaje())==null)
            em.persist(v);
        else
            em.merge(v);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Vaja> vrniVse() {
        log.info("VajeBean: vrniVse");
        return em.createQuery("select v from Vaja v").getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public Vaja najdi(int idVaje) {
        log.info("VajeBean: najdi");

        System.out.println("najdi: " + idVaje);

        return em.find(Vaja.class, idVaje);
    }

    @Override
    public void izbrisi(int idVaje) {
        log.info("VajeBean: izbrisi");
        em.remove(najdi(idVaje));
    }

    @Override
    public Vaja spremeniInVrni(Vaja v) {
        em.detach(v);

        Vaja ret = new Vaja();
        ret.setDelTelesa(v.getDelTelesa());
        ret.setIdVaje(v.getIdVaje());
        ret.setNaprava(v.getNaprava());
        ret.setNazivVaje(v.getNazivVaje());
        ret.setOpis(v.getOpis());
        ret.setSifraVaje(v.getSifraVaje());
        ret.setSlika(v.getSlika());
        ret.setVideo(v.getVideo());

        return ret;
    }



}
```

and i am trying to update the Vaja parameters, and find the by the id in this jsfbean:

```
package si.um.jpa2.jsf;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import si.um.feri.aiv.Klub;
import si.um.feri.aiv.obvescanje.ObvescanjeBeanLocal;
import si.um.jpa.vao.Vaja;
import si.um.jpa3.ejb.VajeBeanLocal;

@ManagedBean(name="zrnoVaje")
//@SessionScoped
public class VajeJSFBean {

    Logger log=LoggerFactory.getLogger(VajeJSFBean.class);

    private Vaja v = new Vaja();
    private Vaja izbranaVaja;

    @EJB
    VajeBeanLocal vbl;

    public void dodajVajo() {
        log.info("VajeJSFBean: dodajVajo");
        try {
            vbl.dodajVajo(v);
            v = new Vaja();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        };
    }

    public void spremenjenaVrednost(ValueChangeEvent event) {

        String vrednostEventa = (String) event.getNewValue();

        System.out.println("spremenjenaVrednost: " + vrednostEventa);

        if(vrednostEventa==null)
            v = new Vaja();
        else {
            v = vbl.najdi(Integer.parseInt(vrednostEventa));
        }
    }

    public void izbrisiVajo(int idVaje) {
        log.info("VajeJSFBean: izbrisiVajo");
        try {
            vbl.izbrisi(idVaje);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        };
    }

    public void izberiVajo(int idVaje) {
        log.info("VajeJSFBean: izberiVajo");
        try {
            izbranaVaja = vbl.najdi(idVaje);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        };
    }

    public Vaja getV() {
        return v;
    }
    public void setV(Vaja v) {
        this.v = v;
    }
    public VajeBeanLocal getVbl() {
        return vbl;
    }
    public void setVbl(VajeBeanLocal vbl) {
        this.vbl = vbl;
    }
    public Vaja getIzbranaVaja() {
        return izbranaVaja;
    }
    public void setIzbranaVaja(Vaja izbranaVaja) {
        this.izbranaVaja = izbranaVaja;
    }
}
```

here is my add/update page (dodajVajo.xhtml):

```
<html
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

    <h:body>
    <ui:composition template="WEB-INF/template/template-trener.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="title">
            Dodaj/uredi vajo
        </ui:define>

        <ui:insert name="header">
        </ui:insert>

        <ui:define name="naslov">
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <h1>Dodaj/uredi vajo</h1>
            </div>
        </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="content">
            <f:view>
                <h:form>
                    <h:selectOneMenu style="margin:auto; display:block;" onchange="submit()" valueChangeListener="#{zrnoVaje.spremenjenaVrednost}">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="NOVA VAJA"/>
                        <f:selectItems value="#{zrnoVaje.vbl.vrniVse()}" var="vaja" itemValue="#{vaja.idVaje}" itemLabel="#{vaja.nazivVaje}" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                    <br />
                </h:form>

                <h:form>
                    <table align="center">
                        <tr>
                            <td>ID vaje:</td>
                            <td><h:inputText id="idVaje" readonly="true" value="#{zrnoVaje.v.idVaje}" required="true"></h:inputText></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Šifra vaje:</td>
                            <td>
                                <h:inputText id="sifraVaje" value="#{zrnoVaje.v.sifraVaje}" required="true">
                                    <f:validateLength minimum="2" maximum="45" />
                                </h:inputText>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><h:message for="sifraVaje" style="color:red" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Naziv vaje:</td>
                            <td>
                                <h:inputText id="nazivVaje" value="#{zrnoVaje.v.nazivVaje}" required="true">
                                    <f:validateLength minimum="2" maximum="100" />
                                </h:inputText>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><h:message for="nazivVaje" style="color:red" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Del telesa:</td>
                            <td>
                                <h:inputText id="delTelesa" value="#{zrnoVaje.v.delTelesa}" required="true">
                                    <f:validateLength minimum="2" maximum="45" />
                                </h:inputText>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><h:message for="delTelesa" style="color:red" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Naprava:</td>
                            <td>
                                <h:inputText id="naprava" value="#{zrnoVaje.v.naprava}" required="false">
                                    <f:validateLength minimum="2" maximum="45" />
                                </h:inputText>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><h:message for="naprava" style="color:red" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Opis:</td>
                            <td>
                                                                                    <!-- style="resize: none" -->
                                <h:inputTextarea row="10" col="10" id="opis" value="#{zrnoVaje.v.opis}" required="true">
                                    <f:validateLength minimum="2" maximum="255" />
                                </h:inputTextarea>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><h:message for="opis" style="color:red" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Slika(URL):</td>
                            <td>
                                <h:inputText id="slika" value="#{zrnoVaje.v.slika}" required="false">
                                    <f:validateLength minimum="2" maximum="255" />
                                </h:inputText>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><h:message for="slika" style="color:red" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Video(URL):</td>
                            <td>
                                <h:inputText id="video" value="#{zrnoVaje.v.video}" required="false">
                                    <f:validateLength minimum="2" maximum="255" />
                                </h:inputText>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><h:message for="video" style="color:red" /></td>
                        </tr>

                <!--        
                v nadaljevanju še dropdown z blank prvim za vnos, ostali pa ob izboru prikaže izbranega, ki ga lahko pol uredi
                 -->



                    </table>

                    <br />

                    <h:commandButton class="btn btn-success" style="margin:auto; display:block;" value="Shrani" actionListener="#{zrnoVaje.dodajVajo}" action="vseVaje.xhtml"/>
                </h:form>
            </f:view>
        </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

the problem is as follow (and i've been really hard at working trying to fix this). my updated entries are duplicated (aka the original stays and the updated one is added as a new one). an i've looked at the detached/merged state of the entityes and all but heres how it goes:

when i select an existing Vaja from fropdown, the method sets it to the Vaja v in JSFBean (the id is correct - 1), but when i change the values and then click submit (calls method dodajVajo in JSFBean), the id is reverted back to the original default (0) as if adding a new Vaja. and so my ejbBean is searhing for a Vaja with id 0, that doesnt exist, which goes to the else condition that just pesrists a new one insted of merges (only because the id is changed when submitting)

any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind -.- the sessionscoped annotation was commented out in jsfbean and reverted at the new request....

Comment: Then please remove the question...